# My repaint() method is not calling the paintComponent() from another class

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I made a box from another class that extends JPanel, the thing is, the paintComponent() is not getting called after I do repaint() from another class. I don't know how repaint works and I am trying to practice some work.

Here's my JFrame:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import KeyActions.keyActions;
import Objects.Piece;

public class createWindow extends JFrame {
    
    public createWindow() {
        super();
        myPanel panel = new myPanel();
        keyActions actions = new keyActions();
        KeyListener key = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                
                
                
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                
                keyAction(e.getKeyCode());
                
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                
                
                
            }
            public void keyAction(int keycode) {
                switch (keycode) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        actions.keyUP();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
            
        };
        
        add(panel);
        addKeyListener(key);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

Here's my code from the JPanel:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Objects.Piece;

public class myPanel extends JPanel {
    
    //main character
    public Piece innerLayer = new Piece(25, 25, 50, 50, new Color(255, 255, 0), "self");
    
    public myPanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        g2d.setColor(innerLayer.color);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
        g2d.drawRect(innerLayer.x, innerLayer.y, innerLayer.width, innerLayer.height);
        System.out.println("I am get called");
    }
    
    
}
```

And this is my keyAction:

```
package KeyActions;

import Main.myPanel;

public class keyActions {
    
    myPanel panel = new myPanel();
    
    public void keyUP() {
        int x = panel.innerLayer.getX();
        int y = panel.innerLayer.getY();
        y--;
        
        panel.innerLayer.addPosVal(x, y);
        panel.repaint();
        System.out.println("keyUp is called");
    }
    
    
}
```

After the keyUP is called, the repaint() didn't call the paintComponent(), it should println "I am get called" but it did not.

Here's my code from the Piece object:

```
package Objects;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Piece {
    
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Color color;
    public String type;
    
    public Piece(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color, String type) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    
    public void addPosVal(int x, int y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }
    
    
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. All the classes in the JDK follow this convention. Learn by example and follow Java conventions. 2) Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting) for custom painting. _"I don't know how repaint works"_ 
From the Java Tutorials: "But the most important change is the invocation of the repaint method. This method is defined by java.awt.Component and is the mechanism that allows you to programatically repaint the surface of any given component."